# Pentaho database join slower than single query in IDE

Tags: pentaho, database-performance, pdi

I'm using a PDI transformation which consists of different steps, and one of them is a *database join* who gets just 1 value as input, execute the query (only 1 time) then the results are manipulated and so on. That step is enormously and painfully slow (over 40 mins).

The same query via Toad by Oracle is executed in 1-2 seconds.
I tried with and without each optimization hints, nothing changes, there is a lot of performance difference between PDI and the single execution via Toad.

```
SELECT /*+PARALLEL(4)*/
    COUNT(T.ID_VAL) AS number_of_occurences, T.name
    FROM TABLE T
    WHERE     1 = 1
    AND T.col1 = 'S'
    AND T.col2 IS NULL
    AND T.name IN
    (
        SELECT /*+INDEX OTHER_TABLE GROUP_ID_INDEX*/ DISTINCT TAB_O.name
        FROM OTHER_TABLE TAB_O
            WHERE     1 = 1
            AND TAB_O.GROUP_ID = ?--'10052023'--PASSED VALUE
            AND TAB_O.col1 = 'M'
    )
    GROUP BY T.name
```

where `T.name` is the same as `TAB_O.name`.

The structure of my transformation is:

[image]

The parameters of the step are:

[image]

Why there is this difference?

An example of the two tables coud be:

OTHER_TABLE:

| GROUP_ID | COL1 | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S | John |
| 1 | M | Mark |
| 2 | S | Marc |
| 2 | M | Jenny |
| 2 | S | John |
| 10052023 | S | Al |
| 10052023 | M | John |
| 10052023 | M | Jack |

TABLE:

| ID_VAL | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Al |
| 2 | Al |
| 3 | John |
| 4 | Jack |
| 5 | Jack |
| 6 | Jack |

So I want as a result:

| number_of_occurences | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 3 | Jack |

I think the problem lies with pentaho preparing queries, or computational overhead, I don't know how Pentaho executes queries.

Adding some infos about the environment, I am using a local instance of a Pentaho on a VM, which connects to the repository hosted on another server.